# Instance member storage cannot be used on type StorageReference

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm writing an application using Firebase and I have this part of the code:

```
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
let usersStorage: StorageReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker.delegate = self

    let storage = StorageReference.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://........")

}
```

And the error says that Instance member storage cannot be used on type StorageReference. I have no idea where is a mistake. I would be thankful if anyone could help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that StorageReference doesn't have a method called storage().  You can verify that for yourself by [looking at its API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference).

I suspect you meant to call [`Storage.storage()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/Storage#storage) instead, and use that to create a new StorageReference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `Storage`, not `StorageReference`. From the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference):

```
// Get a reference to the storage service using the default Firebase App
let storage = Storage.storage()

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
let storageRef = storage.reference()
```

With the above definition for `storage`, you can also look up the reference by its URL:

```
spaceRef = storage.reference(forURL: storagePath)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thank you for the help :)